# Can we use regular expression in Golang testable example Output comment?

Tags: go

I have an example that performs some timing and output the result at the end. Since the result will never be the same, is there a way to use regular expression or something similar in the Output comment?

Something like below:

```
...
// Output:
// Time: \d*\(s\)
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Just encountered the same problem. My output is written by a 3rd party library that includes a timestamp. I hope this is offered in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we use regular expression in Golang testable example Output comment?

No.

This must match literally.

Comment: Thanks. Since output is text I would have expected regular expression to be supported.